# Apache htaccess subdomain redirect error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I have a problem that I do not get solved. I want to make subdomains such
user1.domain.com, user2.domain.com and so continuously. user1, user2, user ... are
users on my site. How to write a query in htaccess?
any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You need to activate the per-user directories first : see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/en/howto/public_html.html

Then you can you `mod_rewrite` to alias `user1.domain.com` to `domain.com/~user1`, like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)\.domain\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com/~%1/$1
```

To be simple. You can also make per user RewriteRule if you don't want to use a global setting and you don't have too many users.

Comment: I don't have access to apache configution. How to do this

Comment: Per-user directories can only be activated through apache configuration files. RewriteRules can be added in .htaccess file provide apache allows them, but then you should have the right to modify .htaccess of the site serve at domain.com

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of the wildcard option in apache's **VirtualHost** configuration section, and **mod_rewrite**. An article with some good details can be found here:

http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/358

This would have to be done in your apache configuration httpd.conf file, however, as .htaccess does not allow for **VirtualHost** sections.